# Why are there answered questions in the unanswered question section?

Tags: discussion, support, unanswered-questions

When I click on the UNANSWERED tab in MSE next to the BADGES and ASK QUESTION, I am finding that many of the "unanswered" questions indeed are actually answered. Can anyone please explain the theory behind this phenomena?

Comment: It's a custom definition of "answered". If somebody posts some nonsense as an "answer", that shouldn't create the impression that the question has been answered.

Comment: @DanielFischer ok thx